# How to plot scatter plot at specific point on map in cartopy

Tags: python, matplotlib, cartopy

I am working on ground observatory data in regards to the earths magnetic field. I am working in Python in Jupyter Notebook. Every observatory has a data series plotted as a `plt.scatter` plot like this:

[image: Observatory data plt.scatter plot]

Code:

```
# Function that plots the time series and the data series from a .mat data file 
# (in the dB-direction based on the out-variable), that is associated with the observatory code (based on the sta-variable)
# It also takes an optional argument 'showdatapoints' so its possible to show data points mainly for debugging
def plotdata_stations(filename, sta, out, start, stop, *args):

# Makes the function use one of the three columns (and thus directions of field) in the data series based on input
if out == 'radial':
    dat = 0
elif out == 'theta':
    dat = 1
elif out == 'phi':
    dat = 2
# If the user inputs something else than one of these three, it returns an error and a hint to resolve the error
else:
    print('\nError: Component ' + "'" + out + "'" + ' not recognized...')
    print('\nHint: Try using ' + "'" + 'radial' + "', " + "'" + 'theta' + "' or " + "'" + 'phi' + "'.")

# Try to load file in case the file does not exist
try:
    nam = DataLoad(filename, 'obs_all')
# If the file does not exist, it returns an error and a hint to resolve the error
except:
    print('\nError: File ' + "'" + filename + "'" + ' not recognized...') 
    print('\nHint: Try putting your file in the same folder as this script.')

# If the observatory code is not in the data file, it returns an error and a hint to resolve the error
if sta not in nam and sta != 'all':
    print('\nError: Observatory Code ' + "'" + sta + "'" + ' not recognized...')    
    print('\nHint: Try using an Observatory Code from the Observatory Locations map.')

# Load data from specific station and direction of field
dat = dB_stations(filename, sta, dat)
tim = t_stations(filename, sta)    

# If start is a string but not 'min' and stop is a string but not 'max', print error
if (isinstance(start, str) == True and start != 'min') or (isinstance(stop, str) == True and stop != 'max'):
    print('\nError: Time range is out of bounds in regards to data set...')    
    print('\nHint: Try using a time range that is included in data set or use ' + "'" + 'max' + "'" + ' or ' + "'" + 'min' + "'.")

# Set start and stop to min or max of time series of min or max is chosen
if start == 'min':
    start = min(tim)
if stop == 'max':
    stop = max(tim)

# Print error if time range is out of bounds in regards to the data set
if start < min(tim) or stop > max(tim):
    print('\nError: Time range is out of bounds in regards to data set...')    
    print('\nHint: Try using a time range that is included in data set or use ' + "'" + 'max' + "'" + ' or ' + "'" + 'min' + "'.")

# Get all data associated with station in the specific time range
ndat = []
ntim = []
for x in range(0,len(tim)):
    if start <= tim[x] <= stop:
        ndat.append(dat[x])
        ntim.append(tim[x])

# Sets up the data plot and shows it
plt.figure(figsize=(9,5))
plt.scatter(ntim, ndat, marker='.')
plt.title('Observatory Data from ' + sta + ' in the dB_' + out + '-direction')
plt.xlabel('Years')
plt.ylabel('nT/yr')
plt.show()

# For optional arguments
for x in args:
    # If the optional argument 'showdatapoints' is called it will print the data points bellow the plot
    if x == 'showdatapoints':
        print('\nData series [nT/yr] in the dB_' + out + '-direction = \n')
        print(dB_stations(filename, sta, dat))
        print('\nTime series [Years] = \n')
        print(t_stations(filename, sta))
    # If the user inputs something else than 'showdatapoints', it returns an error and a hint to resolve the error
    else:
        print('\nError: Optional argument ' + "'" + x + "'" + ' not recognized...')
        print('\nHint: Try using ' + "'" + 'showdatapoints' + "' or deleting the argument.")
```

I use "cartopy" to plot the locations of the observatories like this:

[image: Cartopy map plot of observatory locations]

Code:

```
# Function that takes the name of a station, the direction of field, and the range of time to plot from a .mat data file
# and plots the data from the station at the location of the station
def staGlobal(filename, sta, out, start, stop):

# Load data
the = DataLoad(filename, 'theta_obs_all')
phi = DataLoad(filename, 'phi_obs_all')
nam = DataLoad(filename, 'obs_all')

# Uses removeRepetition from earlier on all three data sets
# Remember to use array[#,0] instead of just array[#] on theta and phi, 
# as the theta and phi series is an array inside another array for some reason
the = removeRepetition(nam, the[:,0])
phi = removeRepetition(nam, phi[:,0])
nam = removeRepetition(nam, nam)

# Converts theta and phi from radians to degrees, as cartopy likes
the = np.rad2deg(the)
phi = np.rad2deg(phi)

# Converts theta from colatitude to latitude, as cartopy likes
the = -the+90

# Converts phi from range 0-360 to range -180-180, for convenience
for x in range(0,len(phi)):
    if phi[x] >= 180:
        phi[x] = phi[x]-360

# Load data from specific station and direction of field
dat = dB_stations(filename, sta, out)
tim = t_stations(filename, sta)

# Get location of station
for x in range(0,len(nam)):
    if nam[x] == sta:
        the = the[x]
        phi = phi[x]

# Get all data associated with station in the specific time range
ndat = []
ntim = []
for x in range(0,len(tim)):
    if start <= tim[x] <= stop:
        ndat.append(dat[x])
        ntim.append(tim[x])

# Trying to scale data down to point of obs (this part needs to be fixed/replaced)
###########################################
scax = 3
scay = 5
lonrat = scax*(25+max(tim)-max(ntim))
latrat = abs(min(ndat))
#if phi < 0:
#    latrat = abs(min(ndat))-scay
#else:
#    latrat = 0
ntim=np.multiply(ntim,scax)
ndat=np.divide(ndat,scay)
###########################################

# Plots data from obs at the location of obs
plt.scatter(phi, the, color='red', marker='.')
plt.scatter(ntim+phi+lonrat, ndat+the+latrat, color='blue', marker='.')
```

All I want to do is plot the `plt.scatter` plot for the observatory at the location of the observatory on the cartopy map. I would love to make it look similar to this:

[image: Desired output]

Is there any way to plot a scatter-plot/curve at a specific point on the map?
You would absolutely save my project if you could help me with this. If you need more info to help me with this, feel free to ask. I am new to this forum so bear with me if this is too vague.

Comment: Where's your code?

Comment: Haha sorry about that, i have updated the post to include the code used for the two plots now.

Comment: I'm not familiar with cartopy but you can achieve this either with the mathematical way and plot the points derived from your station coordinates , or just insert an image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it the mathematical way like this:

```
# Scaling data down to point of obs
###########################################
scax = 3
scay = 4
ntim=np.subtract(ntim,2000)
ntim=np.multiply(ntim,scax)
ndat=np.divide(ndat,scay)
###########################################

# Plots data from obs at the location of obs
# Plot at locations by adding coordinates of obs and subtracting the mean of each axis of data set
plt.scatter(ntim-np.mean(ntim)+phi, ndat-np.mean(ndat)+the, color='blue', marker='.')
plt.scatter(phi, the, color='red', marker='.')
```

But if anyone knows of a more "scientific" way to do it, i would welcome your reply.